# How to run Background task in react native using java code? (when app is killed time also)

Tags: android, react-native, background-task

I need sheduled track play in my react native app.If sheduled time app is kill , how to play track that time?

I tried React-native-background task and react native fetch  libararies but not work properly when app is killed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly your case, maybe play music. I suggest you play music in service and startForegroundService keep service running when app kill like notification.
Here document: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services.